# If date is (certain date) then

Tags: vb.net

How would I make my application do an event when there is a certain date? I can't seem to find something that works. Year doesn't matter, just day and month is all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since day and month is all you want to match on:

```
Dim myDate As Date = Date.Now
Dim someMonth As Integer = 4
Dim someDay As Integer = 13

If myDate.Month = someMonth AndAlso myDate.Day = someDay Then
    ... month and day are matched
End If
```

Comment: myDate.month and others, aren't declared.

Comment: You get the idea, right? Just substitute 'thisDate' for 'myDate', and 'certainDate.Month' for 'someMonth' - you can work out the rest.

Comment: I don't understand :/

Comment: I've changed my example, but you have to apply your own logic to your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Use IsDate....

```
If IsDate(MyDate) Then.....
```

Update various ways of defining date

```
'DateTime constructor: parameters year, month, day, hour, min, sec
 Dim MyDate1 As New Date(2012, 12, 10, 12, 0, 0)

 'initializes a new DateTime value
  Dim MyDate2 As Date = #12/10/2012 12:00:52 AM#

 'using properties
  Dim MyDate3 As Date = Date.Now
  Dim MyDate4 As Date = Date.UtcNow
  Dim MyDate5 As Date = Date.Today
```

Comment: If MyDate were to be, 10th of January, what would that look like?

Comment: You can also test dates that are string e.g from textboxes etc. So   If IsDate(TextBox1.Text) then.... or If IsDate("10/12/2014") then.... are both valid ways of using the statement

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim thisDate As Date = New Date(2014, 4, 13)  ' Assuming this is provided
Dim certainDate As Date = New Date(2013, 4, 13)   ' Assuming this is provided

If thisDate = New Date(thisDate.Date.Year, certainDate.Month, certainDate.Day) Then
    Debug.Print("dates equal excluding year")
Else
    Debug.Print("dates UNequal excluding year")
End If
```

Rememebr, this will always create a new date object for comparison but it works.

Hope it helps!